# SQL Can you count a column and aggregate by the column and group by the date?

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I am new to SQL and am trying to get a count for a calculated field. Typically I use the GUI to build it out, but as I am learning syntax it sometimes seems easier to extract and update manually. Stumped on how to get a count for this calculated field. Looking to get a total count by the tool name and then group it by date. For this scenario, we have about 20 tools and we would like to see how many events per day per tool the system is receiving.

Here is the query being run.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   COUNT(DISTINCT("REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL")) AS "TOOL COUNT",
   "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL",
   CASE
      WHEN "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'ALARM%' THEN 'PATROL'
      WHEN "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'DELL_EMC%' THEN 'DELL_EMC'
      WHEN "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'Eye of the Storm%' THEN 'ENTUITY'
      WHEN "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'NECTAR%' THEN 'NECTAR'
      WHEN "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'NINTEX%' THEN 'NINTEX'
      WHEN "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'oci_%' THEN 'OCI'
      WHEN "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'OEM%' THEN 'OEM'
      WHEN "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'OPSMVS%' THEN 'OPSMVS'
      WHEN "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'PROXY_CONVERGED_%' THEN 'PROXY_CONVERGED'
      WHEN "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'SCOM%' THEN 'SCOM'
      ELSE "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL"
   END AS "TOOL",
   "INFO_F"."DATE_RECEPTION",
   "INFO_F"."DATE_RECEPTION",
   "D"."REPEAT_COUNT",
   "D"."ITSM_INCIDENT_ID",
   "D"."MC_OWNER",
   "D"."MSG",
   "D"."MC_HOST",
   "Custom Event Slots"."_GROUP"
FROM "SLOTS_O"
INNER JOIN "D"
ON (
   "SLOTS_O"."SERVER_ID" = "D"."BPPM_SERVER_ID"
   AND "SLOTS_O"."MC_UEID" = "D"."MC_UEID"
)
INNER JOIN (
   select
    a.mc_ueid,
    a.bppm_server_id,
    a.slot_name as cust_pid_slotname,
    a.slot_value as cust_pid,
    b.slot_name as assigned_group_slotname,
    b.slot_value as assigned_group,
    c.slot_name as cust_assignmentkey_slotname,
    c.slot_value as cust_assignmentkey,
    d.slot_name as cust_slotname,
    d.slot_value as cust_mnemonic,
    e.slot_name as cust_type_slotname,
    e.slot_value as cust_type,
    f.slot_name as cust_ci_slotname,
    f.slot_value as cust_ci
from
    event_extended_slots_o a,
    event_extended_slots_o b,
    event_extended_slots_o c,
    event_extended_slots_o d,
    event_extended_slots_o e,
    event_extended_slots_o f
where (
    a.mc_ueid=b.mc_ueid and
    a.mc_ueid=c.mc_ueid and
    a.mc_ueid=d.mc_ueid and
    a.mc_ueid=e.mc_ueid and
    a.mc_ueid=f.mc_ueid and
    a.slot_name='cust_pid' and
    b.slot_name='assigned_group' and
    c.slot_name='cust_assignmentkey' and
    d.slot_name='cust_mnemonic' and
    e.slot_name='cust_type' and
    f.slot_name='cust_ci'
    )

) "Custom Event Slots"
ON (
   "Custom Event Slots"."MC_UEID" = "SLOTS_O"."MC_UEID"
)
INNER JOIN "INFO_F"
ON (
   "D"."MC_UEID" = "INFO_F"."MC_UEID"
   AND "D"."BPPM_SERVER_ID" = "INFO_F"."BPPM_SERVER_ID"
)
INNER JOIN "CLASS_D"
ON (
   "INFO_F"."BPPM_SERVER_ID" = "CLASS_D"."BPPM_SERVER_ID"
   AND "INFO_F"."EVENT_CLASS_KEY" = "CLASS_D"."EVENT_CLASS_KEY"
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN "REPORTER_D"

ON (
   "INFO_F"."BPPM_SERVER_ID" = "REPORTER_D"."BPPM_SERVER_ID"
   AND "INFO_F"."TOOL_KEY" = "REPORTER_D"."TOOL_KEY"
)
WHERE (
   "INFO_F"."DATE_RECEPTION" >= trunc(sysdate)-7 AND
       (
        "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'ALARM%' OR
        "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'DELL_EMC%' OR 
        "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'Eye of the Storm%' OR
        "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'NECTAR%' OR
        "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'NINTEX%' OR
        "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'oci_%' OR
        "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'OEM%' OR
        "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'OPSMVS%' OR
        "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'PROXY_CONVERGED_%' OR
        "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL" LIKE 'SCOM%' OR
      )
     )
GROUP BY 
   "D"."REPEAT_COUNT",
   "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL",
   "REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL",
   "D"."ITSM_INCIDENT_ID",
   "INFO_F"."DATE_RECEPTION",
   "D"."MC_OWNER",
   "D"."MC_HOST",
   "Custom Event Slots"."BMCPS_ASSIGNED_GROUP",
   "D"."MSG"

ORDER BY
   COUNT(DISTINCT("REPORTER_D"."MC_TOOL")) DESC
```

I have tried a few count options and that does not get me what I need, so looking to see if it's possible and if so, what the correct syntax is.

Comment: Try using `MAX("DATE_RECEPTION")` so that you only return the most recent date/row for the *other* data values. Also take it out of the GROUP BY of course. Another approach is to write a smaller subquery that does not include the dates. Join the subquery to your main table and get the dates from the outer query.

Comment: Wwoww... Please edit question and add create real table script and insert samlpe some data... Actually this query is not work.... Or use northwind database for sample.

Comment: I forgot about the MAX(attr) option, I will play with that to see if I can get something working. I'm fairly new to working with SQL, so I will see if I can find examples of sub queries and apply. I have been working with the query builder in the UI and then tweak from there, so expanding out by doing something radical like a sub query is almost crazy talk. :D Thanks @JacobH!

Comment: Subquery is as simple as doing `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM YourTable)`. So really, there's not any extra work besides putting parenthesis around your existing query and then doing another SELECT. It's very not radical! It can get a bit hard to read (and poor performance) if you nest a lot of them.

Comment: Thank you, again. I will play around with it and see what I can work out. I was probably being a little dramatic to use the word radical. ;)